# How can I reinitialize or destroy `infiniteajaxscroll` V3?

Tags: ajax, infinite-scroll, jquery-ias

How can I `reinitialize` IAS or `destroy` on V3? (no jquery, I am using import InfiniteAjaxScroll from '@webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll';)

There's also no `reinitialize` or `destroy` on their doc (https://docs.v3.infiniteajaxscroll.com/reference/methods)

```
Infinite Ajax Scroll version: 3
Browser version: FF Dev 71.0b5 (64-bit)
Operating System: OS Catalina (10.15.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [`unbind`](https://docs.v3.infiniteajaxscroll.com/reference/methods#unbind) to remove all event listeners. This should be enough to "destroy" IAS.

Otherwise you can probably overwrite the variable that contains the IAS instance.

Pseudo code example:

```
// previous instance
var ias = InfiniteAjaxScroll(/* options */);

// destroy
ias = null

// reinitialize
ias = InfiniteAjaxScroll(/* some other options */);
```